# Can I replace an under mount sink with a drop in sink without replacing the countertop?

Tags: plumbing, sink, countertops

I have bathroom basins I wish to replace with ones that are above counter will this work for me with the holes that have been made from sunk in basins or are we talking new bench tops?

Comment: Seems related [How do we convert our drop-in sink to an undermount one?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/how-do-we-convert-our-drop-in-sink-to-an-undermount-one)

Comment: The appropriate way to say "thank you" is to click the up arrow next to the answer(s) that help you and the check mark next to the one that helped the most. In this case, there's only one answer, so it gets both. Also, thanks for coming back (even if it's been 4 years) to respond! Better late than never.

Answer (score 4):

I have replaced bathroom sinks of various types with ceramic style sinks that sit from the top of the vanity cabinet surface.

This work best if the before and after sinks both had the faucet holes as part of the sink body itself. Another factor to consider is selecting a new sink that will work within the hole size of the old sink. This can make the replacement job tremendously easier, particularly if the existing vanity has a tile top.

I have found that you should be prepared to fully replace the drain down pipe, p-trap and drain line to the wall. Differences in sink dimensions and basin depth will likely leave it difficult to fit the old stuff to the new sink. Besides the new parts are not that expensive and it is far more pleasant to fit up clean new parts.

Comment: +1 for "far more pleasant to fit up clean new parts" - it's easier, too, if the old parts are corroded as well as soiled.